# Pagination with SoundCloud API Search

Tags: search, soundcloud

Accoding to the API document Search and Pagination section on http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#search

I build my query URL like:

https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?q=U2&client_id=xxxxxxxx

It did only return 10 results.

Even I add limit and offset parameters to make results with Pagination, like "&limit=20&offset=20", it is still only 10 results returning.

Does it mean we can not use pagination with soundcloud search API?

Comment: My application relies on this pagination and it used to work but it no longer does. It seems to have broken a some point in the last week. I've noticed that when I search with just limit=100&offset=0 it returns 100 results but limit=100&offset=0&genres=trance returns 10 results.

Comment: This is a bug on our side. We're looking into it and will let you know when we have a resolution.

Comment: This was a temporary bug and I have now confirmed that soundcloud has resolved this issue. This question can be closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a bug in the SoundCloud API and should be resolved now. Please comment if you are still experiencing the problem.

Comment: This problem is NOT resolved.

I am getting very strange results from the pagination. When making a request with a limit of 51 items I get 39 results. If I change to limit to 26 ,then I get 19 results.

Example calls:

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?offset=0&q=tuesday&limit=51&client_id=1234&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200

http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks?offset=0&q=tuesday&limit=26&client_id=1234&format=json&_status_code_map[302]=200

Comment: This problem is still not resolved. There's still inconsistency in the results